# How can I generate GIF images in .NET?

Tags: .net, image, gif, image-generation

Is there a .NET library I can use to programmatically generate my own GIF images?

At a minimum I'd like to build it pixel-by-pixel.  Better would be support for text and shapes.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.  I mocked this up in Photoshop…

[Number line graphic http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/5458/dollarlineot9.gif](http://img143.imageshack.us/img143/5458/dollarlineot9.gif)

What do you recommend?

Comment: Is there any particular reason is needs to be a .gif format image? The only reason I can think of for using a .gif is if the image needed to be animated. If not, other formats (such as png and jpg) offer much better compression rates and more flexibility...

Comment: No particular reason.  GIF is a simple lossless format with wide web browser compatibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(xSize, ySize, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
  // Use g and/or bmp to set pixels, draw lines, show text, etc...
}
bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Job done

Comment: Exactly. Read up on the System.Drawing namespace to understand how to draw the lines needed etc.

Comment: Although technically you can't really set pixels with the Graphics object (you can fill 1-pixel rectangles). SetPixel and GetPixel are on the Bitmap object.

Comment: I stand suitably corrected.
The comment should read 'Use g and/or bmp to ...'

Comment: Accepted or not, this doesn't seem to allow for animation in GIF images. (Not that I think the web needs more of them, but for the sake of completion.)

Comment: What does it take to make animated GIFs?

Comment: .NET doesn't support encoding animated GIF images. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET

Comment: What is wrong with System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder?  It is available from WPF by default.

Comment: Whats about ***NGif*** https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET ?

Answer (score 4):

note that in addition to the `bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Gif);` method, there is a `bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Gif);`  which allow you to create & output an image to a webpage, without it ever to saved to your servers hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the beginnings of doing so with the classes in the `System.Drawing` namespace.  It draws a line with two boxes to demonstrate support for shapes at a higher level than simply setting pixels.

```
// add a reference to System.Drawing.dll
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(400, 100);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0.0f, 0.0f, 400f, 100f);

                // draw line
                using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1.0f))
                {
                    g.DrawLine(p, 0, 49, 399, 49);
                }

                // Draw boxes at start and end
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 0, 47, 5, 5);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 394, 47, 5, 5);
            }


            bmp.Save("test.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
            bmp.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the System.Drawing namespace? Everything you need should be in there.

Answer (score 1):

An example of how to use a HTTPHandler to create the image and send out in a stream (using the image code already posted here).

Use:

```
<img src="createChart.ashx?data=1"/>
```

Code:

```
public class CreateChart : IHttpHandler
{
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
        string data = context.QueryString["data"]; // Or get it from a POST etc

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(xSize, ySize, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Image)) 
        {
           // Use g to set pixels, draw lines, show text, etc...
        }
        BinaryStream s = new BinaryStream();

        image.Save(s, ImageFormat.Gif);

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(s);
        context.Response.End();
     }

     public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you should be able to skip the BinaryStream and write it directly to the Reposnse:
bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a chart control instead of trying to generate GIFs? Unless the requirements are strictly to generate this particular GIF, I think using a chart control offers you more flexibility.

Comment: No. But the question didn't limit answers to .NET Framework. It said a ".net library".

Comment: actually, it is now: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I like [my company's products](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/photopro/default.aspx).  You will be able read/write gifs and create them from whole cloth.  It's runtime royalty free for desktop apps, licensed for servers.

Answer (score 0):

[Generating Images On-the-Fly with ASP.NET](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=25487) (Feb 22, 2002) by Stephen Walther